# Use Net/HTTP to create specific cURL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, riak

I have this cURL that works fine running from terminal but I need it to be dynamic so I need to make this call from my model.

```
curl -XPUT -H "content-type:application/json" http://localhost:8098/riak/demo2 -d '{"props":{"precommit":[{"mod":"riak_search_kv_hook","fun":"precommit"}]}}'
```

This is what I get so far but it is not working, there are no errors and the response is empty. I don't expect anything to be returned, but this should create a new `Riak` bucket and it doesn't. I have tested, as I said, on my terminal and it works fine, it creates the bucket as expected.

```
require "net/http"
require "uri"

uri = URI.parse("http://localhost:8098/riak/dg1_logs")

http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)

request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri.request_uri)
request.content_type = "application/json"
request.body = '{"props":{"precommit":[{"mod":"riak_search_kv_hook","fun":"precommit"}]}}'

response = http.request(request)

p response.body
```

**More details**

I'm using `Riak` and I need to enable the `Riak Search` on my client bucket and it is possible only running this cURL. I need to make it dynamic so when my client creates a new account, I already make his buckets able to `Search`

I'm using Ruby 1.9.3

Comment: Why not use Ruby's OpenURI? It's an easier path to walk.

Comment: [Riak Ruby Client](https://github.com/basho/riak-ruby-client)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem might be that in the curl example you use HTTP *PUT* and *POST* in the ruby example.

By the way you would save yourself some pain if you would have used something like [RestClient](https://github.com/archiloque/rest-client) - way easier to work with than net/http API.

And finally, I don't think it's a good idea to make HTTP requests from a model (assuming you mean AR model), you should probably create a separated object to take care of it for you.